# Pd.read_html to read complicate table

Tags: python, pandas

I try to use pandas to read some complicated table, merged cells, I think.

I want to know if it is possible to read tables like what I attached in right format, or there are good tools for that.

[image: a table to read]

Comment: What is your input (where can I find the html table), and what is your expected output, and what does `pd.read_html()` return, if not your expected output?

Comment: this is the table code

Comment: here
this is the table code
[link](https://pastebin.com/ySBSpJuU)
I can not get the multiindex column work, no matter what option I tried.